# Getting Color Values C#

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble with this one problem. I'm trying to compare Color RGB in a list
and sort them by there RGB. I've thought about adding it to a dictionary but don't know exactly how to get the values of the colors once their added to the Dictionary. So how would can I get the RBG of color in a list to compare them with one another. Any help or advice and I will be grateful, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Color.ToArgb()? MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb.aspx

Comment: Could you also explain what the comparison is supposed to do? Are you trying to see which color is more red than another or more dark? Where do you get colors from and in what format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use System.Drawing.Color structure for this. 
It provides an [toArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb.aspx) method which you can use to get the equivalent integer value of a color.

```
List<Color> lc = new List<Color>();
Color c = new Color();
c.R = 0xFF;
c.G = 0x00;
c.B = 0x00;
lc.Add(c);
...
...
lc.Sort((c1, c2) => c1.ToArgb().CompareTo(c2.ToArgb));
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example

```
//if you want to compare each value
Color _color = Colors.AliceBlue;
byte R = _color.R;
byte G = _color.G;
byte B = _color.B;
```

use [compareTo](http://www.dotnetperls.com/compareto) also for byte comparison

Comment: Yes the CompareTo method must return a integer though.

Comment: it is simple.. you can easily compare these bytes and return an integer value according to the result